# Finding conditional density functions for the following scenarios

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I'm trying to find the conditional probability density function for the following scenarios and wondering if they are correct

> A number x is chosen at random in the interval [0, 1], given that x > 1/4.

$f(x|1/4<x<1) = 4/3 \space for \space 1/4<x<1$

$f(x|1/4<x<1) = 0 \space otherwise$

> A number t is chosen at random in the interval [0, $\inf$) with exponential
>   density $e^t$, given that 1 < t < 10.

$f(t|1<t<10) = \frac{e^{-t}}{e^{-1}-e^{-10}} \space for \space 1<t<10$

$f(t|1<t<10) = 0 \space otherwise$

> A dart is thrown at a circular target of radius 10 inches, given that it
>   falls in the upper half of the target.

$f((x,y)|y>0) = \frac{1}{50\pi} \space for \space y>0 \space and \space x^2+y^2<100$

$f((x,y)|y>0) = 0 \space otherwise$

> Two numbers x and y are chosen at random in the interval [0, 1], given
>   that x > y.

$f((x,y)|x > y) = 2 \space for \space x > y \space and \space x,y\in[0,1]$

$f((x,y)|x > y) = 0 \space otherwise$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct.

Well, that is assuming that darts do indeed land on dart boards with uniform distribution.

The support for the last one can *also* be expressed as $0\leqslant y<x\leqslant 1$.